# Is it better to duplicate values in a pivot table and add different fields or create another table connected to the pivot table?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I currently have this schema:

**trainings**

```
id
name
```

**speakers**

```
id
first_name
last_name
```

**training_speaker**

```
id
training_id
speaker_id
```

**training_speaker_dates**

```
id
training_speaker_id
date
time
```

When getting trainings with their speakers, I use the `training_speaker` pivot table.

```
class Training {
  public function speakers() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Speaker')->using('App\TrainingSpeaker');
  }
}
```

A speaker in a training can have multiple dates and times. That's why I have added `training_speaker_dates` though it's getting hard to query the `training_speaker_dates` from the `speakers` method of the `Training` class.

I'm thinking of this approach

```
class Training {
  public function speakers() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\TrainingSpeaker')->with('speaker')->with('dates');
  }
}

class TrainingSpeaker {
    public function speaker() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Speaker');
    }

    public function dates() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\TrainingSpeakerDate');
    }
}
```

In that way, I can easily get the speakers with their dates. But is there a better approach?

I'm also thinking of removing `training_speaker_dates` table and add the `date` and `time` fields in the `training_speaker` table since I can just duplicate values (same `training_id` and `speaker_id`) but with unique primary keys.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have better structure now.

You will lose convinience of belongToMany relation and it's convinient methods.

As I understand you have a problem with eager loading.

You could solve it with this solution: https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/1089.

Then you could eager load pivot relations in `with()` and `load()` methods:

```
$trainings = Training::with('speakers.pivot.dates')->get();

@foreach($trainings->speakers as $speaker)
    @foreach($speaker->pivot->dates as $date)

    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Pay attention, that example from github uses deprecated helpers `str_*` and `arr_*`. You should replace it with `Str::` and `Arr::` facades.

Comment: I'll check this one. Thank you sir.